# Login in WEB API template

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have set up a `Web Api` project in `Visual Studio 2015` with Individual Authentication. This provided me a template containing `AccountController`  I can find Register action and Password related Actions. I have seen there methods `AddExtrenalLogin` and `ExternalLogins`. Is'nt it there a simple Login method which uses same data as registered from that to complete the flow. Can any body please guide how to add our own Login with token based authentication, our any example from scratch which describe the basic infrastructure of API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Web API Login method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503455/asp-net-web-api-login-method)